# DDD/SoC w/Ninject Design Question?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

So I have been really struggling to grasp the concept, but I am making progress :)

Anyway I have a question, using the Service/Repository/UnitOfWork/EF 4 w/POCOS approach.

My MVC app can reference my Repository layer, that References System.Data.Entity, to setup the bindings in Ninject to the concrete classes that live there, and as long as I use Interface driven design, that does not tie my MVC app to EF. Correct?

Just by referencing an assembly that references System.Data.Entity, you are not tying your MVC application to EF?

If I am wrong, can someone please tell me how to bind the interfaces to the concrete classes of the repository and unitfowork in the Ninject Module in the MVC app.

Make any sense?

Comment: I think of it as a dependency tree. In your case, root is the mvc app. The root can talk just to its children (repository layer). But for everything to work, all descendants of the root must be present.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Just by referencing an assembly that references System.Data.Entity, you are not tying your MVC application to EF?

Yes, you are tying it but that shouldn't bother you. The MVC application is the Host application, it is where all layers and assemblies need to be aggregated into a final product that is deployed on a web server and just works. Jeffrey Palermo has a [nice blog post](http://jeffreypalermo.com/blog/the-onion-architecture-part-1/) about onion architecture you might take a look at. In this pattern outer layers of the onion  know about the inner layers but not the opposite (inner layers shouldn't know about the outer layers). The ASP.NET MVC application is the outermost layer. Then you could simply change the outer layer with some other Host application (for example WPF) and reuse the inner layers.

Comment: Yes I looked at the Onion Architecture, and believe it or not, it made complete sense to me, I just keep having this thing in my head that says to maintain the IoC, the MVC app can't know of anything other then the layer directly beneath it, but in the Onion Architecture, it says exactly the opposite, you can in fact reference any layer below you. So moral of the story, it is ok to reference the repository layer from the MVC app, in fact you have to, correct?

Comment: @Sam Striano, you have to reference it in term of assembly reference. But of course your controllers should never know anything about it and work only with its abstraction.

Comment: I think it has finally clicked!! Thanks for all of your help, you are a Gentleman and scholar!